# Inverse of matrix $A$

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&&0&&\cdots&&0&&1\\-1&&1&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\\vdots&&\ddots&&\ddots&&0&&\vdots\\\vdots&&&&\ddots&&1&&1\\-1&&\dots&&\dots&&-1&&1\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to determine $\|A\|_\infty\|A^{-1}\|_\infty$.

$\|A\|_\infty=n$.

Can someone help me determine $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Is the entire lower-left half filled with $-1$? And the entire top-right half (except the final column) filled with $0$s?

Comment: It is not so easy to guess the values. Is the whole lower left triangle -1?

Comment: @Arthur Yes all $-1$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method for computing the inverse.

First, compute the inverse of 
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}1&&0&&\cdots&&0&&0\\-1&&1&&\ddots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\\vdots&&\ddots&&\ddots&&0&&\vdots\\\vdots&&&&\ddots&&1&&0\\-1&&\dots&&\dots&&-1&&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We can do so by noting that $B = I - N$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $N = I - B$ is lower triangular.  Notably, $N$ satisfies $N^{n} = 0$ and $N^{n-1} \neq 0$.  We can calculate
$$
(I - N)^{-1} = I + N + N^2 + \cdots + N^{n-1}.
$$
You'll notice that the powers $N^k$ of $N$ follow a "nice" pattern, so this inverse can be expressed in closed form.

From there, we can use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to compute a rank-1 update to the inverse.  In particular, take $u = (0,\dots,0,1)$ and $v = (1,\dots,1,0)$ (both column-vectors).  We then have
$$
A^{-1} = (B + uv^T)^{-1} = B^{-1} - \frac{B^{-1}uv^TB^{-1}}{1 + v^TB^{-1}u}.
$$
I hope that helps.